# How to close a UDPSocket in julia?

Tags: udp, julia

How to close a UDPSocket once it is created in Julia by sock = UDPSocket()? Is there a equivalent to close(sock) as in Python?

Answer (score 1):

as described in the [IO/Network docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/io-network/?highlight=udpsocket#Base.close): `close(sock)`

Answer (score 1):

this is the definition of `UDPSocket` in [socket.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/socket.jl):

> ```
> ## SOCKETS ##
> abstract Socket <: AsyncStream
> ...
> ...
> # UDP
> type UDPSocket <: Socket
> ...
> ...
> ```

it's a kind of `stream`, so we can use `close()` to close it.

however, we must initialize the `sock` before running `close(sock)`:

```
sock = UDPSocket()
bind(sock,ip"a.specific.ip.address",port)  #init sock
...
...
close(sock)
```